# How to run counts from text file for different functions

Tags: python, count, external-data-source

I have a task where I need to run certain functions based on a text file to count certain text. The first set of instructions I was able to do myself as it is not user based and it is just a general count of text items in the text file (tasks.txt). My problem I am having now is how do I calculate certain things from a text file based on user only. There is currently only one task but if I had more than one task assigned and to a different user how would I do the calculations for that specific user only? Any advice would really be appreciated.

The Text File is: (tasks.txt)

> User assigned to task:
>
> bobby
>
> Task Title :
>
> Fly
>
> Task Description:
>
> Fly to the moon
>
> Task Due Date: 2020-04-01
>
> Date Assigned: 2020-03-03
>
> Task Completed:
>
> No
>
> Task number:
>
> 1

1st set of tasks: (completed)

> The total number of tasks that have been generated
>
> The total number of completed tasks.
>
> The total number of uncompleted tasks.
>
> The total number of tasks that haven’t been completed and that are overdue.
>
> The percentage of tasks that are incomplete.
>
> The percentage of tasks that are overdue.

2nd set of tasks (User Based):

> The total number of tasks assigned to that user.
>
> What percentage of the total number of tasks have been assigned to that user?
>
> What percentage of the tasks assigned to that user have been completed?
>
> What percentage of the tasks assigned to that user must still be completed?
>
> What percentage of the tasks assigned to that user have not yet been completed and are overdue?

My code so far:

```
data2 = open('tasks.txt').read()
    count3 = data2.count('Task Title')
    count4 = data2.count('Yes')
    count5 = data2.count('No')

    with open("tasks.txt", "r")as f5:
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        overdue = 0
        for line in f5:
            if not line.startswith('Task Due Date'): continue
            field, value = line.split(':')
            if field == 'Task Due Date':
                if datetime.datetime.strptime(value.strip(), '%Y-%m-%d') < today:
                    overdue = overdue + 1
            ab = (overdue/count3)*100
            abb = (count5/count3)*100
            print("Total number of tasks: " + str(count3) + "\nTotal number of completed tasks: " + str(count4) + "\nTotal number of incomplete tasks: " + str(count5) + "\n" +
            "The percentage of overdue tasks is: " + str(ab) + "%" + "\n" + "The percentage of incomplete jobs is: " + str(abb) + "%")
            num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('user.txt'))
            print("The number of registered users is: " + str(num_lines) + "\n")
            data3 = open('tasks.txt','r').read()


            usr_check = input("Please input a user name to write details of that user.\n")
            count6 = data3.count(usr_check)
            count7 = (count6/count3)*100
            print("The user " + str(usr_check) + " has total tasks of: " + str(count6) + "\n" + str(usr_check)+ "'s" + " " + "percentage of total tasks is: "
            + str(count7) + "%")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first read the file, create Objects (class Task), and for each task create a new class, append it into an array with these object.

An object should contain

- user
- title
- dates

And every important information, so later you can work with them easily.

Then you can run through that list and count the number of task (yes, a len() is a better way), you can create a dictionary, and dinamically add keys (users that is assigned to a task) and count how many tasks correspond to a specific user, and all the process you need to get done.

Whats better is in the dictionary, you could use a normal list to contain the objects correspond to a user, so you can count that list, you can group objects by being done or nor, and so on.

Specific data structures is easier to work with. I recommend using classes for tasks.